# create multiple movie thumbnails using ffmpeg (one at a time) failing

Tags: c#, process, ffmpeg

I'm using this small bit of code to create thumbnails of videos being uploaded to my site:

```
public static void GetThumbnail(string video, string thumbnail)
{
    var cmd = "ffmpeg  -itsoffset -1  -i " + '"' + video + '"' + " -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s 320x240 " + '"' + thumbnail + '"';
    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
        FileName = "cmd.exe",
        Arguments = "/C " + cmd
    };

    var process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = startInfo
    };

    process.Start();
}
```

I'm uploading the videos one at a time asynchronously.  The first video thumbnail gets created just fine, but each subsequent one does not get created.  I've noticed that if I try to delete subsequent videos from the file system, it says it can not delete them because they are in use by ffmpeg.  I can delete the first one that finished processing just fine.  I have to kill the ffmpeg process from task manager for all of the others that it's holding open.  Why is ffmpeg only working the first time through and then holding the video's open in an open process afterwards?

I also tried creating multiple thumbnails one at a time from the command prompt and that worked fine (the process does not stay open either).

What am I missing in my c# code to make sure the process finishes, and then terminates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

doh!  really dumb on my part.  I was using the same file name for each thumbnail and there was a dialog coming up in the command line asking if I wanted to overwrite my existing thumb image.

when I changed the filename to be dynamically created, everything is peachy.